# Forms Based Authentication Users in the SharePoint 2010 People Picker Not Working

Tags: 2010, web-part, claims-based-auth

I Created custom login page .

I use this code for login

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(Username.Text, Password.Text))

{

    SecurityToken tk = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(

        new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url), "ADProvider", null,

        Username.Text, Password.Text);

    if (tk != null)

    {

        SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam = SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current;

        fam.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(tk);



        //look for the Source query string parameter and use that as the redirection

        string src = page.Request.QueryString["Source"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(src))

        {

            Response.Redirect(src, false);

        }

        else

        {

            Response.Redirect("/", false);

        }

    }
```

I add connectionstring and membersgip for webconfig

```
  <connectionStrings>

<add name="AdConn" connectionString="LDAP://domain.local/DC=domain,DC=local" />
```

```
...

<membership defaultProvider="i">

  <providers>

    ...

    <add 

      name="AdProvider" 

      type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 

      connectionStringName="AdConn" 

      enableSearchMethods="true" 

      attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />

  </providers>

</membership>

...
```

but when i login , i get

**Error: Access Denied**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Central Administration and go to Application Management.now  hit User Policy ribbon option in the Web Applications Management page having selected your web application.  Hit Add Users in the Policy for Web Application dialog.  Hit Next in Add Users dialog.  Use the Browse button in the Choose Users people picker control.  Notice the Select People and Groups dialog that comes up is changed.  Noticeable difference is that there are sections like Active Directory, All Users, Forms Auth & Organizations.  Type in an active directory user alias and search.  There should be 2 results for the same user.  Select the user from Forms Auth result.

[image]

Now, your Policy for Web Application dialog should look like Image

[image]

I use [this](http://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/sharepoint-2010-claims-authentication-custom-login-form-part-1-modifying-your-config-files/) link. It is useful for me.

Comment: good that you solved it. Please elaborate a bit in the answer on how this solved your issue. Those external links tend to be shorter lived than our site, so please insert a few lines and **then** link :-) thx