# Custom MembershipProvider: applicationName

Tags: 2010, web-config, membership-provider

I'm creating a custom MembershipProvider for FBA authentification.

When I access the root url of the web app `http://sp:6336/`, my provider is initialized. Value of "applicationName" in web.config is ok. I save it to private field.

Then I choose "FBA" in combobox.

Then, in validate user, value of "applicationName" is lost. Because I am in another instance of the custom membership, and "current" web.config is the one of central administration!

What is wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this link is usefull for you: [Forms Based Authentication Users in the SharePoint 2010 People Picker Not Working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34897/forms-based-authentication-users-in-the-sharepoint-2010-people-picker-not-workin/36296#36296)